# What should be standard size of QR code on business card so that it can get scan easily?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, figma

What should be the standard size of QR codes on business cards so that they can get scan easily?

Comment: Take a look at the official QR website: https://www.qrcode.com/en/howto/

Answer (score 1):

I would question if a QR code on a *business card* is [necessary](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57209/is-the-use-of-a-qr-code-worth-the-space-it-requires). Business cards aren't generally "advertisements". The purpose of a *business card* is to provide contact information. If the QR code merely *repeats* that same information, I'm not so sure it's beneficial. Imagine someone taking the time to grab the phone, scan the code, and see that it merely repeats the same data they are staring at on the card. No added value.

If the card **is** an *advertisement* - with the sole purpose of getting the reader to scan the code - make the code as large as possible while still being aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: It was an assignment given in my college. I am also not sure if it is mandatory or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, there is no standardized QR code size. I probably would not want to go smaller than .75" x .75". Put a QR code on the business card and test it out at various sizes. See if you could test with a couple of phones as well.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the specific QR code. As a QR code is a visual representation of a string of text; the size of the QR code depends on the length of the URL/text. If you got a very long URL you may want to use a URL shortening tool.

If you do this in Indesign (which is the appropriate tool for biz card creation, whereas photoshop is for photo editing and figma is for UI design) it will generate the QR code at the recommended size (I think once got told rule of thumb not smaller than 70% of that). Meaning **recommended 0.9mm** or **at least 0.6mm** width of pixel. But of corse also depends on distance of scanning so on poster it should be bigger than on biz card.

So long story short, there is no way to tell for sure apart from printing and testing it. And for the most part, if you think how good it still can be printed and if the squares are visible when viewed by a camera, you should be able to guess quite good if it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Value:** I agree with what Scott said above about if a qr code actually adds value, but I would also argue that time is valuable as well. Consider the qr code leads to a homepage. Back in 2021 a lot of us found that this was annoying to get your phone out and use the scanner, but in 2023 you just simply point your camera at it (especially using an iPhone), and you can go straight to the link so the vale is;

- Saving time as I don't have to type in the address.

  Zero percent chance of error (how many of us have typed in a wrong
  URL and unable to get to the website by one letter that didn't type
  or was misspelled by the user).

Therefore QR codes can make it very useful to help users or future clients get to that place you need them to go.

**Size:** With technology constantly changing what wouldn't work yesterday may work today. I usually test first. ***My latest QR code is 28.5px only, so while in illustrator I size down my project to the approx size of a business card, grab my phone and see if it works.*** Test done. I also believe, especially for certain companies such as digital marketing, or people like programmers we need to show through our business card that we're at the forefront of technology and a qr code whether used or not does this (but definitely make sure it works:)

Comment: The problem with qr codes is that they connect to phones and frequently i want work related stuff to go to a computer instead. If i wanted stuff on phone i would just read the qrcode and ditch the card entirely. So why card at all.

Comment: So mobile goes up and down https://contentsquare.com/blog/mobile-vs-desktop/ as you can see between 2020-2022 but still leads at the end with 58%; also one may say conversions are higher with desktop at 3.7% vs mobile at 2.2%. But when you hold these conversions up a little closer you're looking at around 20 vs 30 conversions per 1000 visits. If you were to leave mobile out completely you'd still be looking at losing around 40% in sales. Again, it does depend on your target market as well, but as we factor UX we should factor what is going to make life easier for our users/potential customers.